# Migration from UA to GA4. Not able to receive event on GA4 dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I have a existing UA dashboard with property ID (say UA-ABC). Now created a GA4 dashboard and have a measurement ID ( say GA-XYZ ). I was using a below python script to send the data to UA dashboard. Now replaced the UA tracking ID in the script with GA4 measurement ID. Not able to receive the events in the GA4 dashboard.

```py
import requests

MEASUREMENT_ID = 'G-XYZ'
CLIENT_ID = '555'
EVENT_CATEGORY = 'video'
EVENT_ACTION = 'play'
EVENT_LABEL = 'holiday'


payload = {
    'v': '1',  
    'tid': MEASUREMENT_ID,  
    'cid': CLIENT_ID,  
    't': 'event',  
    'ec': EVENT_CATEGORY,  
    'ea': EVENT_ACTION,  
    'el': EVENT_LABEL,  
}


response = requests.post('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', data=payload)


if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Event successfully sent to Google Analytics')
else:
    print('There was an error sending the event to Google Analytics')
```

Note: The events are going to the UA dashoard if I use UA tracking in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the 
[Measurement Protocol (Universal Analytics)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide?hl=en)
  which is designed to send hits to a universal analytics account.

Endpoint

```
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

payload_data
```

If you want to send hits to a GA4 account then you need to use [Measurement Protocol (Google Analytics 4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4)

The endpoint is also diffrent

```
POST /mp/collect HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.google-analytics.com
Content-Type: application/json
<payload_data>
```

Remember ga4 is not the same as UA your going to have to redesign your hits and convert them to events.

Event Payload example

```
{
"client_id": "x",
"events": [
  {
    "name": "offline_purchase",
    "params": {
      "engagement_time_msec": "100",
      "session_id": "123"
    }
  }
]
}
```

That and the measurement protocol for ga4 is extremally limited. You will probably not be able to send all the hits you want to most of them are locked down for use by googles internal sdk's.   Have a look at the [event-builder](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/event-builder/) you will be able to see what you can send.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was able to send the data to the new GA4 dashboard. But the events are only appearing after around 48 hours and the real-time report and users is zero. Is there anything that I missed during the new dashboard creation?

Comment: nope sounds about right to me.   48 hours is the standard processing time.    I wouldn't be surprised if measurement protocol doesn't work with real-time reports this may be one of those things they have locked down to the internal services only.